# Optional table layout and index

Tags: postgresql

We are collecting stats and have a few options on how we store it in our db.  It's an array with up to 1000 objects in it per row and thousands of rows.  We have two different structures we can use.

```
Option 1:
    [
      {
        "04a32156-6ad6-49f4-a0c6-9d6ddf784595": [
          {
            "B": false,
            "C": "2627",
            "O": null,
            "P": 38494
          },
          {
            "B": false,
            "C": "2273",
            "O": null,
            "P": 45900
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "fcd2cf78-09dc-436b-be87-b768eab989f5": [
          {
            "B": false,
            "C": "1836",
            "O": null,
            "P": 2212
          },
          {
            "B": true,
            "C": "2080",
            "O": null,
            "P": 2105
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

or

```
Option 2:
    [
      {
        "H": "04a32156-6ad6-49f4-a0c6-9d6ddf784595",
        "D": [
          {
            "B": null,
            "C": "2644",
            "O": [
              "398500"
            ],
            "P": 23035
          },
          {
            "B": null,
            "C": "2320",
            "O": [
              "4346629"
            ],
            "P": 25076
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "H": "fcd2cf78-09dc-436b-be87-b768eab989f5",  
        "D": [
          {
            "B": null,
            "C": "1614",
            "O": [
              "53034"
            ],
            "P": 18364
          },
          {
            "B": null,
            "C": "2380",
            "O": [
              "102000"
            ],
            "P": 19249
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

We need to query all the data in those objects where id = '04a32156-6ad6-49f4-a0c6-9d6ddf784595'

Which is the better structure and what's the best way to index?  No other items need to be indexed other than the id here.

Answer (score 0):

The best for simple and fast queries is a normalized schema:

```
CREATE TABLE object (
   h uuid PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE data (
   data_id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   b boolean,
   c integer NOT NULL,
   o integer[],
   p integer NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE object_data (
   h uuid REFERENCES object NOT NULL,
   data_id bigint REFERENCES data NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (h, data_id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON object_data (data_id);
```

Comment: yea the big challenge here is it's much faster to insert a 1x2MB blob into the db than 1000 x 2KB rows which is the main reason we can't go down that path.

Comment: DId you try with `COPY`?